# Splitting a common deliverative to individual variables

Tags: python

I have written a simple program that monitors a COM port and converts the line into a string. I then use decode to ASCII, which is working fine.

My problem is that I need to split the string into separate variables.

Example string:

```
1,40.20,23.50,NOW()
```

I would like to split it to:

```
a    = 1
b    = 40.20
c    = 23.50
d    = NOW()
```

Comment: do you mean `a, b, c, d  = yourstring.split(',') ` ?

Comment: `a, b, c, d = my_string.split(",")` Though I might be tempted to keep those as a list rather thna unpacking them

Comment: does `NOW()` represent future stream inputs or some function that should be stored as a value to return dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of objects then you can just split on the `,` and assign the elements:

```
a, b, c, d = txt.split(',')
```

If you do not know the number of objects then it would be appropriate to store the results in a List:

```
my_list = txt.split(',')
```

and then access using my_list[0] etc.

It IS possible to create variables 'on-the-fly' to cope with a unknown number but this is definitely not recommended not least because name conflicts can later occur. For example:

```
names = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx"
l = len(my_list)
for i, v in enumerate(my_list):
    if i < 26:
        globals()[names[i]] = v
```

and then variable names are `a` etc